# Powershell script is unable to send the email alert

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-4.0

I am not getting the email alert when the ever my load process  fails, below is my script. Please let me know where I am doing wrong and suggest a way to make the condition work

```
$body = Get-Content -Path D:\APPDATA\FDMEE\Scripts\output.txt | Out-String 
$fail = Get-Content "D:\APPDATA\FDMEE\Scripts\output.txt" | Select-String "FAILED" 
if($fail-eq "$True"){Send-MailMessage -From "sharihar@xpioc.com" -To ""sharihar@xpioc.com""-Subject " Load failed on the Production Server." -Body "$body"  -Attachments "D:\APPDATA\FDMEE\Scripts\output.txt" -smtpServer mail.xpioc.com}
```

Output.txt content

```
process_id       : 50836
STATUS           : FAILED
RULE_ID          : 16
RULE_NAME        : INTERNATIONAL
```

Answer (score 3):

Change this:

```
$fail = Get-Content "D:\APPDATA\FDMEE\Scripts\output.txt" | Select-String "FAILED" 
if($fail-eq "$True")
```

To this:

```
$fail = Get-Content "D:\APPDATA\FDMEE\Scripts\output.txt" | Select-String "FAILED" -Quiet
if($fail)
```

Your code is testing for whether the `$fail` variable contains the string "True" which isn't a match.

Per LotPings comment, if you add the `-Quiet` switch to `Select-String` you get a true/false result. You can then just test for `$fail` to confirm if the true/false result is true.

Comment: I would add that if the result object from `Select-String` is not required that you could use `-Quiet` so that the result is truly a boolean. Not required of course.

Comment: I have modified the script 
if($fail){Send-MailMessage -From "sharihar@xpioc.com" -To ""sharihar@xpioc.com""-Subject " Load failed on the Production Server." -Body "$body"  -Attachments "D:\APPDATA\FDMEE\Scripts\output.txt" -smtpServer mail.xpioc.com}.
Now I am getting email alert eventhough the load run fine. I believe , I am not supposed to receive the email alert for if ($fail) condition, correct me, if I am wrong. I guess, it is not recognizing the string.

The output.txt 

process_id       : 50893
STATUS           : SUCCESS
RULE_ID          : 16
RULE_NAME        : INTERNATIONAL

Comment: Mark without the `-Quiet` parameter to sls the var `$fail`will contain `STATUS           : FAILED` and the if will always be true as $fail isn't empty